# WordPress Header Code Generates Both https and http for Stylesheet and JavaScript files

Tags: wordpress, ssl

We are using WordPress Twenty Fourteen theme. The page header code generated for mobile devices shows file sources from both http and https. Later Newer Apple devices are blocking these files from loading.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentyfourteen-lato-css'
        href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato%3A300%2C400%2C700%2C900%2C300italic%2C400italic%2C700italic&subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&display=fallback'
        media='all' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='genericons-css'
        href='http://wordpress.wwfry.org/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/genericons/genericons.css?ver=3.0.3'
        media='all' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='twentyfourteen-style-css'
        href='http://wordpress.wwfry.org/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/style.css?ver=20190507' media='all' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='twentyfourteen-block-style-css'
        href='http://wordpress.wwfry.org/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/css/blocks.css?ver=20190102' media='all' />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]> <link rel='stylesheet' id='twentyfourteen-ie-css' href='http://wordpress.wwfry.org/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/css/ie.css?ver=20140701' media='all' /> <![endif]-->
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='fh-buttons-css' href='https://fh-kit.com/buttons/v2/?green=26890d' media='all' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='tablepress-default-css'
        href='http://wordpress.wwfry.org/wp-content/plugins/tablepress/css/default.min.css?ver=1.14' media='all' />
    <script src='http://wordpress.wwfry.org/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0' id='jquery-core-js'></script>
    <script src='http://wordpress.wwfry.org/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2'
        id='jquery-migrate-js'></script>
    <link rel="https://api.w.org/" href="https://www.wwfry.org/index.php?rest_route=/" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/json" href="https://www.wwfry.org/index.php?rest_route=/wp/v2/pages/8" />
    <link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="https://wordpress.wwfry.org/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
    <link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml"
        href="http://wordpress.wwfry.org/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" />
    <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 5.8.1" />
    <link rel='shortlink' href='https://www.wwfry.org/?p=8' />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed"
        href="https://www.wwfry.org/index.php?rest_route=%2Foembed%2F1.0%2Fembed&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wwfry.org%2F%3Fpage_id%3D8" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed"
        href="https://www.wwfry.org/index.php?rest_route=%2Foembed%2F1.0%2Fembed&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wwfry.org%2F%3Fpage_id%3D8&format=xml" />
    <style type="text/css" id="twentyfourteen-header-css">
        .site-title a {
            color: #ffffff;
        }
```

Header code generated for desktop / PC devices requests all files using https.

To fix the problem I checked the following:

1. In WP general settings I verified that the WordPress Address and Site Address both used https.
2. I check the header.php, functions.php and theme.php files for any custom coding and found none.

See the website at wwfry.org. Any help debugging this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: hi, perhaps it's hardcoding http somewhere?